# How to find the workflow running instances by JAVA in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

How to find the available workflow instances that are running in an AEM instance Programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the all workflows in your workflow session from the Interface `com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession` by using `Workflow[] workflows = wfSession.getAllWorkflows()`

and you can get the workflow state by using Interface `com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.Workflow` ***getState()*** method. For more information you can look for the workflow api document.

[WorkflowSession API CQ 5.6](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/exec/Workflow.html#getState())

[WorkflowSession API AEM 6.1](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/WorkflowSession.html)

[WorkflowSession API AEM 6.2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/workflow/WorkflowSession.html)